# after upgrade homebrew ocrmypdf Fatal Python error: config_get_locale_encoding: failed to get the locale encoding: nl_langinfo

Tags: python, homebrew, locale

Since I upgraded homebrew (on macOS Catalina 15.5), ocrmypdf issues a weird error.

I issued ocrmypdf

```
% ocrmypdf                                             
Fatal Python error: config_get_locale_encoding: failed to get the locale encoding: nl_langinfo(CODESET) failed
Python runtime state: preinitialized
```

Fatal Python error: config_get_locale_encoding: failed to get the locale encoding: nl_langinfo

What is nl_langinfo ?

I have these environment variables set:

```
LANG=en_us
LC_COLLATE=en_us
LC_ALL=en_US
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
```

But setting these variables does not help.
Settinog export PYTHONHOME=/Users/klaas/homebrew/lib/python3.7 does not help either.
Does somebody know the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found it.

After reading https://bugs.python.org/issue34544

I unset LC_ALL (which was en-US) and Python3.8 (and ocrmypdf) worked !